# Time series database with offline data caching

Tags: android, database, offline, cloud-storage, kotlin

I am looking to develop a system that monitors a sensor using an Android app and uploads that to a remote database for storage and visualisation.

Is there a commonly used architecture which can meet my requirements:

- Store time series data
- Mobile compatible
- Store readings acquired offline and push measurements once the connection is restored

It is likely that the client will not have a stable internet connection and the architecture needs to relay all measurement data recorded once an internet connection is restored.

Previously I have used something such as Google Firebase which has a similar function to store data in a local cache which is then synced and pushed to the cloud once the user comes back online. As I am looking to collect a reasonably large amount of sensor data which the user will only need to push remotely and will not need access to Firebase does not seem like a good solution.

Ideally, as I am familiar with InfluxDB I would like to use something like this for the remote data storage and I am aware of Kapacitor for holding a local cache which is then sent to the server however I am unsure as to whether this is a good solution for a mobile app.

I feel this must be a common situation for which there are solutions.

Thanks in advance.